# Dialogflow pricing and Google Cloud pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to understand text message/google assistant pricing for Dialogflow and Google Cloud combined. For Enterprise Edition of Dialogflow I see the pricing is $0.002 per request (where there is a  cap of 600 requests/min and could be increased upon request at no charge) but then since Enterprise editions are eligible for Google Support, those support plans again have separate pricing for  role based/enterpise editions.

If support is charged separately then what is the $.002 per request charge in Dialogflow? The text messages are unlimited as long per min caps are maintained. Is the $0.002 only if you exceed the cap? if not what is it that I'm paying that amount for?

The pricing for Dialogflow could be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/editions#pricing_and_support_comparison)
The pricing for Google support could be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/)

Answer (score 0):

primarily, you're paying that to get a [Service Level Agreement](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/sla) as well as the ability to be covered under Cloud Support.

The free tier does not have an SLA, nor the ability for paid support.